# ng-click is not working while triggering bootstrap modal dialog

Tags: jquery, angularjs, bootstrap-modal

I have the below requirement in AngularJS + Bootstrap3
    - While triggering the modal dialog need to copy and pass the current table row value to the modal dialog input

My code is here 
HTML:

```
<table class="table" data-sorting="true" data-paging="true" data-paging-size="10"
       data-paging-position="right" data-paging-count-format="{CP} of {TP}">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th data-breakpoints="xs" data-type="number">S.No</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Authorization</th>
      <th>Actions</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="test in vm.testData">
      <td>{{$index + 1}}</td>
      <td>{{test.test}}</td>
      <td>
        <div ng-show="test.authorize">Authorized</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="vm.showEditDialog(test, $event)">
          Edit
        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<div class="modal fade" id="editTestModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="editTestLabel">
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
vm.showEditDialog = function (test, event) {
  vm.selectedTest = angular.copy(test);
  $("#editTestModal").modal('show');
};
```

Comment: You need to use $modal service of ui.bootstrap , info available https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ ,https://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

you may need to use the template tags as below,

```
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
             <div class="modal-body">
                    //you table template tag comes here...                    
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```